# Calculating dates in Acrobat

Tags: javascript, date, acrobat

I'm trying to create an Acrobat form that automatically calculates/increments my dates. What is the javascript I need to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solution:

```
var d1 = new Date(this.getField("Starting").value);
var num = d1.valueOf();
num += 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var d2 = new Date(num);
event.value =util.printd("m/d/yy", d2);
```